# Some examples on what kind of Information can be stored in Info.plist?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, ios7, plist

I am currently thinking on what kind of information, I can store in Info.plist.

I was planning to store the Ip address of the rest server to which the app talks to, but that can be stored as a constant in a configuration file. so what are the other use cases where one uses Info.plist to store some data.

Is it a good practice to store IP address in Info.plist?.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your application and what you're trying to achieve, you can store pretty much anything you'd like in a plist if it's one of the value types referenced in Apple's plist documentation [which can be found by clicking this part of the sentence.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists/AboutPropertyLists.html)

Comment: do you recommend storing IP address in Info.plist?

Comment: Yeah sure, that'll do just fine. It's really your preference, I wouldn't make a whole plist dedicated to just one IP address though.

Answer (score 0):

A plist is just an xml file.  You can store whatever you want in it.  View a plist file as RAW in Xcode by right clicking on it and you can see.

Answer (score 0):

Yes can store IP Addresses too in it, in the form of string or in some number type.

Here you can see the **Property list types and their various representations** (From Apple Documentation) below:

[image]